# Comparing numbers in Slim

Tags: ruby, slim

In Slim, how can you compare numbers?

I want something along the lines of:

```
- if match_percent > 50
  span.classOne
  | #{match_percent} %
- else
  span.classTwo
  | #{match_percent} %
```

But the ">" is regarded as a syntax error. Is this even possible? The documentation for Slim is absolutely terrible. I can't find any information about this anywhere

Comment: Did you consider just putting parentheses after the if around the condition?

Comment: can you post the full backtrace errors?

Comment: Same thing happens when I add parentheses.
And I would post them if I knew how. The exact error is "undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your backtrace errors, this is hard to debug but it should work.

#### test.slim

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Slim Examples
    meta name="keywords" content="template language"
    javascript:
      alert('Slim supports embedded javascript!')

  body
    h1 Markup examples

    #content
      p This example shows you how a basic Slim file looks.

    - if 1 < 2 
        p 1 is less than 2 
    - else
      p No items found. Please add some inventory.
        Thank you!

    div id="footer"
      | Copyright &copy; #{`Time`} #{'me'}
```

Run this from command line with no errors

```
slimrb test.slim
#=>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Slim Examples</title><meta 
content="template language" name="keywords" /><script>alert('Slim 
supports embedded javascript!')</script></head><body><h1>Markup 
examples</h1><div id="content"><p>This example shows you how a basic 
Slim file looks.</p></div><p>1 is less than 2 </p><div 
id="footer">Copyright &copy;  me</div></body></html>
```

#### UPDATE

Based on your comment above:

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

means whatever is called on the left side of `>` in ruby is returning nil. So your bug is simply that. So in your example you could fix this with string interpolation.

```
- if "#{match_percent.to_i}" > 50
  span.classOne
  | #{match_percent} %
- else
  span.classTwo
  | #{match_percent} %
```

This way if `match_percent` is nil, your if statement still works.

Comment: This helped me figure it out - apparently if I put the number first, i.e. "50 < match_percent", it works the way I expected

Comment: @AndrewTorr glad it helped. However, I'm curious what is the value of  `match_percent` in your errored code. Because it's just ruby and shouldn't matter the order or the operator of `<` or `>`

Comment: Turns out it was possible for match_percent to be nil, so I had to add a check for that as well. When it's guaranteed to be a number, I don't get the syntax error.
However, it ended up being simpler to just define a ruby function that takes the match percent as an argument and returns the class name anyway